# Uncaught TypeError encountered in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

I am trying to get my jQuery to work with my Magento. I have added the links for jquery and foundation(both JS and CSS). But when I try to load my jquery, the Uncaught Type error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'foundation'
```

I did add the NoConflict() for my jquery, which is why I don't understand why it should not work.

My code for the head is(in the page.xml):

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/modernizr.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/jquery.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
            // noConflict so we can use both libraries
                $.noConflict(); 
            // your current code here 
            //]]>
    </script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>foundation/foundation.min.js</script></action>
                 <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/foundation.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/main.css</stylesheet></action>  
 </reference>
```

while on my header.phtml I have added this bunch of code after the html part:

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
$(document).foundation();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: true,    
        directionNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,  
        animationSpeed: 900,  
        start: function(slider){
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `jQuery = jQuery.noConflict()`.. and use `jQuery` variable instead of `$` whenever you are using jquery instead of prototype.

Comment: jQuery(document).foundation(); Can I use it for calling the foundation.js? I tried it and it seems to have fixed the jQuery issue, but it can't find the foundation.js, even if it's already been embedded in the <head> tag.